# Execute a dynamic number of .py files

Tags: python

I built up a project structure who kinda look like this :

```
Main.py
   |_ directory1
      |_ directoryA
         |_ script1.py
         |_ script1.sql
   |_ directory2
      |_ directoryB
         |_ script2.py
         |_ script2.sql
   |_ directory3
      |_ directoryC
         |_ script3.py
         |_ script3.sql
```

In reality there is more subfolders, tree nodes and files.

In main.py, I get dynamicly the path of each py files in the subfolders.
Each .py files execute the .SQL file associated.

But I struggle to dynamicly execute each file in a single execution. In a way that if I add a .py file, it will be executed without changing a line in main.py. Because the "execution" would be generic and main py doesn't know the name of the class it execute. And moreover, **I must pass to each py file an database connector instance**

I want to do something like this :

```
# Connector to the database

connecteur = ODBConnector(serveur, base, user, pwd)

### Execution

# Get each .py file in the subdirectories (glob), # return a list of absolute path

files = utils.getFichierParExt(racine, extension)

for file in files:

module = importlib.import_module(file)

module._init_(connecteur)
```

I explored solutions like putting a bash file. But I didn't get to dynamicly iterate files in, nor pass the connector instance.

I imagined each py files as a class at some point to permit the *init* function that I kinda could call without knowing the name of the class.

My question is : how can I do this simply, and moreover, is this a acceptable design in python ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does every scriptX.py  run correctly? You can list the python file in the folder, then use subproccess to run every scriptX.py

Comment: You have already had the script code or you are designing them right now?

Comment: The scripts in the files just grab the connector, execute the SQL script, do some controls on data and export them. I designed it so they mind only their own business ( they don't interact with the main, except retrieving the ODBC instance, nor with others script).

Comment: So you are designing the program that you have not written the script yet? That would be fine to give you some ideas.

Comment: You can define the same function in all script, then call it for every script. You can also use reflection in python. just google reflection python.

Comment: Yes these scripts are not ritten, the goal is that we can add a scriptX.py whenever we want and the main will automatically integrate him when we launch execution. It's as simple as : for script in folders : execute(script). That my tentative to execute them with the _init_ definition. Thanks for the tips on reflection I will study that.

Comment: Also if you know about OOP,you can define a base class with virtual function which abstracte business process into,every script define a sub class inherit the base,then you can call the same function for each script.